# Python: How to return data from a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, graph, plotly, plotly-dash

My goal is to create a real-time graph with Dash that displays how long it takes for a batchjob to perform a repetitive task. The graph will get the data from the log-file of the batchjob where it looks for some specific words.

The problem is when i want to display the data in the graph it only shows the first values, not the following values.

I would rather want it to be in two separate functions, but since I have had trouble with the graph I chose to have it in the same function for now.

```py
def update_graph():
    specific_word = "help"

    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if specific_word in line:

            X.append(int(count))
            Y.append(int(time))

            data = go.Scatter(
                x = list(X),
                y = list(Y),
                name = 'Scatter',
                mode = 'lines+markers'
                )

            return {'data':[data], 
            'layout': go.Layout(xaxis = dict(range=[min(X), max(X)]),
                                yaxis = dict(range=[min(Y), max(Y)]))}
```

The result I'm getting is only the first value from the log-file, not the following values.

When i replace the return-line with print(data) and execute the function in the terminal i get the result I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you understand how `for` loops and `return` interact? your function will always return the first time your `if` conditional evaluates to `True`

Comment: @aws_apprentice , I'm not 100% sure about how it works, but that is what i guessed.. Is there a way to solve the problem or do i have to remake everything?

Comment: what should the expected output look like?

Comment: you can create an empty list/array, before the for loop, and inside the for loop create a statement if correct will push them into the list/array, and after the forloop return the list/array

Comment: @aws_apprentice for each value it should append to list, X = (count of the task), Y = (time (ms) between each task). But as i said, it only appends the first values for X and Y...

Scatter({
    'mode': 'lines+markers', 'name': 'Scatter', 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'y': [109175, 1190, 1178, 1783, 1641, 1000]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that python exits the function after returning the first value.

You can add all the values you want to see into a list and return that instead:

```py
def update_graph():
    specific_word = "help"
    output = []  # the list output will store all the data
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if specific_word in line:

            X.append(int(count))
            Y.append(int(time))

            data = go.Scatter(
                x = list(X),
                y = list(Y),
                name = 'Scatter',
                mode = 'lines+markers'
                )

            output.append({'data':[data],  #add the values to the list
            'layout': go.Layout(xaxis = dict(range=[min(X), max(X)]),
                                yaxis = dict(range=[min(Y), max(Y)]))})
    return output
```

So you would get a list as the return value.

You can iterate over the list to get whatever elements you want:

```py
thelist = update_graph()

for item in thelist:
    print(item)
    #do whatever you want with the item here
```

Answer (score 0):

A return statement breaks out of a loop.So this doesn't allow the for loop to continue executing.
To resolve this issue you can store the data inside the for loop and place the return statement outside the function.

You could try this -

```
array_name.append( {'data':[data], 
            'layout': go.Layout(xaxis = dict(range=[min(X), max(X)]),
                                yaxis = dict(range=[min(Y), max(Y)]))})
```